# Balls and Bins problem with constraint

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Assume we have $B$ black balls and $R$ red balls, where $R+B$ is a multiple of 4. We want to distribute the balls in $\frac{R+B}{4}$ bins such that each bin has at least 1 red ball and at least 1 black ball and also each bin has a total of 4 balls. What is the probability a randomly selected bin has 2 red and 2 black balls?

I am trying to approach the problem in two phases as follows, but it's getting very complicated to count all of the possibilities. 
Phase 1: place one black and one red ball in each bin (to account for the constraint)
Phase 2: place the rest of the balls in the bins and count all the possible ways.

An alternative approach could be to exclude the 1st phase and go directly to the second, but I don't know if this is correct. Any ideas? If we do this, we get:

$\Pr(\text{2 Black, 2 Red | all bins have at least 1 Black and at least 1 Red})=\frac{\binom{R-(R+B)/4}{1}\binom{B-(R+B)/4}{1}}{\binom{(R+B)/2}{2}}$

Comment: That's what I'd do...

Comment: Any ideas on how to count them?

Comment: Leave the fixed balls out of the picture, how would _you_ compute the probability of 1 red and 1 black in a random bin?

Comment: I would say it is $\frac{\binom{R-(R+B)/4}{1}\binom{B-(R+B)/4}{1}}{\binom{(R+B)/2}{2}}$ but I don't see why this is true.

Comment: I think an easier way to approach this problem is to replace $R$ with $R-\#\text{bins}$ and $B$ with $B-\#\text{bins}$ and calculate the probability you get a bin with 1 black and 1 red.  If you have a condition that governs every bin, then it's probably overcomplicating things.

Comment: To compute the probability, one needs to have some idea of the process by which the balls are placed in the bins. Are all legal distributions to be considered equally likely? That is a physically unlikely assumption.

Comment: Yes, all the combinations are equally likely. Essentially we try to use the classical definition of probability, so this assumption is unavoidable.

Comment: To add to @AndréNicolas comment. One must of course assume that both $R$ and $B$ are at least $\frac{R+B}4$. Now there are two ways to proceed: (1) assign each ball randomly to a bin, check if the conditions are met, and start over if not; (2) select $\frac{R+B}4$ red and $\frac{R+B}4$ black balls, distribute one of each to each bin, than then randomly assign the remaining balls. It is not obvious to me that these will produce the same probability distributions, and if not you must specify which is used. The first procedure ensures that every legal assignment is equally likely, the second not.

Comment: Also note that you did not require $4$ balls to go into each bin, while the requirement that $R+B$ be divisible by $4$ suggests that this may have been an intended requirement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the requirement. I will add it explicitly in the dscription above.